# Possible independence of head-tail or tail-head flip

Tags: probability

When examining an arbitrary number of independent tosses of a coin, and looking for the possibility of a changeover (from a head to a tail or a tail to a head), I understand that the probability of this happening at the cth toss (denoted by the event Zc) is: 2p(1-p), where p is, say, the probability of a head being tossed.

What if we have to consider another event: Zf (probability of a changeover occurring at the fth toss), and are looking for the probability of the intersection of the two, i.e. P(Zc∩Zf).

Now, if c=f, then the two events are the same, and the probability would remain 2p(1-p).

If f happens to be one more than c, then we would want changeovers on successive tosses, would the probability of that be (2p(1-p))^2? These two events would then be independent would they not?

And what if the difference in c and f were more than the one toss? Looking at the intersection of the two, do we need to take into account the number of non-changeovers that might occur between changeovers at the cth and fth toss? Or would (2p(1-p))^2 still hold as that probability?

Thanks!

Comment: What?${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly: if $c=f+1$ (or the other way around) you are looking for a sequence Head-Tail-Head or Tail-Head-Tail. Since the tosses are independent you get
$$P(Zc \cap Zf)= p(1-p)p+(1-p)p(1-p)=p(1-p)$$
which is not $P(Zc)P(Zf)$.
If $|c-f|>1$, i.e. $c$ and $f$ are more than 1 apart from each other, then you can use independence, since $Zf$ only relates to tosses $f$ and $f-1$ and $Zc$ only relates to tosses $c$ and $c-1$ and they don't "overlap"